# How can I list my twitter followers list in WinJS.UI.ListView

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I want to list all my twitter followers in my WinJS.UI.ListView.

```
        WinJS.xhr({
            url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=" + twitterusername,
            responseType: "json"
        }).then(
                function (xhr) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    var a = [];
                    a = json.ids;
                    //
                    // now what next?
                    //
                },
                function (error) {
                    myListView.textContent = error;
                }
            );
```

I get all my twitter follores id by `json.ids`.
But next how to find their screen names and prifile pictures and main thing how to bind them with my ListView control. Becouse I had bind simple my static data into ListView but for this example i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make another call for each ids to `api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=json.ids[i]`.

After you receive all callbacks, you have to create an array with objects that have title, text and picture properties. After that simply bind it with you list.

The following code is an exemple (not tested, don't know if it's functional, but it should point you in the right direction)

```
var followersCallback = function(xhr){

          var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          var promises = [];

          // make promises for each user id (call to twitter to get picture/name/description)
          for (var i = 0; i < json.ids.length; i++){

            var promise = WinJS.xhr({
                url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=" + json.ids[i],
                responseType: "json"
            });

            promises.push(promise);

        }

        var dataArray = [];

        // join those promises
        WinJs.Promise.join(promises)
                     .then(function(args){
                        //when you get callback from all those promises
                        for (var j = 0; j < args.length; j++){

                            //not sure if parse is needed
                            args[j]=JSON.parse(args[j].responseText);

                            //populate your data array
                            var obj = {};
                            obj.title = args[j].name;
                            obj.picture = args[j].profile_image_url;
                            obj.text = args[j].description;
                            dataArray.push(obj);
                        }
                        //bind your data to the list
                        var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);

                     });
    };

    WinJS.xhr({
                url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=" + twitterusername,
                responseType: "json"
            }).then(
                    followersCallback,
                    function (error) {
                        myListView.textContent = error;
                    }
            );
```